# How to save numbers that stand in front of x, y, z in expression in to variables, A,B,C

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a different plane functions in form:

Ax+By+Cz =0

I need a factors A, B, C which stand in front of variables x, y and z.
Is there any function in Mathematica to do something like this?

Comment: You can search for "coefficients" or something like that in the documentation center.  And there's also the `Information[]` search `?*Coeff*`, which yields a bunch of functions related to coefficients.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Though nothing in the question indicates that OP is aware of anything close to Coeff :)

Comment: @Kuba That's a basic mathematics question, then. :)  But I was just trying to teaching someone to fish with the `?` fish hook.  It's certainly a tool I use, esp. in the ``?*`*xxxf*`` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Coefficient[A*x + B*y + C*z, {x, y, z}]
```

> {A, B, C}

Comment: Thanks you this is best solution I get a list with coefficients.